# vuejs group records within a foreach

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a settings table and I would like to set up an interface for the user to select which options he will use, using checkbox, and I would like to group this list by two columns of the table "modulo" and "submod" I tried to do this using a forearch and a control variable, but as I understand it I cannot update the control variable within a foreach.

[image: my table]

what I did was

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container">

    <div v-for="nivel in niveis" :key="nivel.Valor">
        <span v-html="separaModulos(nivel)" />
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="niveisSel" :value="nivel.Valor"/>
        <label>{{nivel.Nome}}</label>
    </div>


  <p>{{niveisSel}}</p>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { listaRegistros } from '@/api/geral'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      niveis: null,
      niveisSel: [],
      modulo: '',
      submod: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    separaModulos(reg) {
      if(this.modulo !== reg.Modulo || this.submod !== reg.Submod) {
          let xret = ''
          if(this.modulo !== reg.Modulo)
             xret += '<hr /><h2>' + reg.Modulo + '</h2>'          

          this.modulo = reg.Modulo //error
          this.submod = reg.Submod //error
          xret += '<p>' + reg.Submod + '</p>'

          return xret
      }
    },
    listaNiveis() {
      listaRegistros('Sistema/ListaNiveis').then(response => {
        this.niveis = response.registro //json from server
      }).catch(err => {
      })
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.listaNiveis()
  }
}
</script>
```

I get the error "**You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.**" when trying to change the value of the control variable.

what I need is to group the records, it can be on a card or accordion, how can I do that?
Expected result:

[image: Expected result:]

Comment: Use a computed to create a new data structure that is better for looping, and use the `v-for` on that computed.  Don't use any method in the template and don't use `v-html`.

Comment: I will try to create a new structure that is appropriate to the case, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, update the question if you run into a problem